# Undo aws s3 policy to deny all users all actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I accidently set the s3 bucket policy to deny all actions to a bucket for all users

```
        {
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
          },
          "Action": "s3:*",
```

Now I cant delete anything in the bucket or even remove the bucket. I can't do anything to the bucket anymore. I can't even remove it with cloudformation.

Is there a way to undo this or somehow remove this bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test this, I created a bucket and added this Bucket Policy:

```
{
  "Id": "TryThis",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "NoBucket",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "NoObjects",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Indeed, **I was unable to:**

- List contents
- Upload objects
- Edit the Bucket Policy

However, I was able to use the **Delete Bucket** command in the AWS Management Console.

I then repeated the experiment and logged in using my [Root Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html). I was then able to **delete the Bucket Policy** and restore all functionality to the bucket. Root credentials have full access to an AWS account.

Comment: I just tested this, it seems like I wasn't able to delete the bucket in AWS Console. But as root user, I could delete the bucket policy.